# What is the best way to pass uint8_t* buffer and size_t bufferlen to API function in C from a C++

Tags: c++, c, libc++

A C function API accepts uint8_t* and size_t as parameters:

```
bool foo(uint8_t* buff, size_t bufflen)
```

What is the best way to manage and handle in C++ layer invoking this API. Is string, vector or list a better option

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure while calling this API from C++ you always pass a `uint8_t` type pointer . normal array `uint8_t arr[x]` (x is any +ve number) will also work. Just make sure address you passed has data of type uint8_t with correct size of the buffer.

e.g. `uint8_t arr[6];` for this the call will be `foo(arr,6);`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `std::vector<uint8_t>` while passing `data()` and `size()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a container to the C function.  You can still use one in your C++ code, but you'll need to pass a pointer to the data, in accordance to what the C function parameters are.  Use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). This is equivalent to an array in C, in that the data is stored contiguously in memory.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> myData;
// ... fill myData
// for c++11 and later,
foo(myData.data(), myData.size());
// pre-c++11
foo(&(myData[0]), myData.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is string, vector or list a better option?

Well, `list` is a non-starter, because it will not store the sequence in contiguous memory. In other words, the C code would not be able to take a pointer to the first element and increment it to get to the second element.

As for the other two, that depends on the rest of your C++ code. I would lean towards `vector` rather than `string`, but you haven't really provided enough context for that to be any more than a general feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would go with a helper class that has an method that either takes a vector, or a custom structure that acts like a span - i.e. a `pair<void*,int>`, or perhaps even a span (but I'm not allowed the C++14 crayons).

If the data really is character-based the std::string and string spans can work well, but if it is really binary data, vector and vector spans are the better encapsulation, IMBO.

I still don't want to call that directly from application code if what is actually in there is structured data. You can easily write a method that takes an expected structure type and generates the pointer and sizeof(instance).

You can write a generic template that would accept any structure and convert it to a void*/char* and length, but that tends to open your code up to more accidents.